# Adding to current command in .bashrc but, only want to change the color of the directory I'm in, to Blue

Tags: macos, terminal, folders, color, customization

I really like the way this looks but, I want my directory to be Blue. Every time I try and alter my .bashrc, I mess the whole thing up. Can anyone help?..

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[32m\]^_^\[\e[37m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]O_O\[\e[31=m\]; fi\`[\u@\h:\w]\\$ "
```

Comment: 1. This question is likely better suited for unix.stackexchange.com
2. Question needs more detail, screenshots, formatting.

Comment: The question is perfectly on-topic here, but definitively needs details.

Comment: Try one of the online generators https://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ps1.html http://bashrcgenerator.com or more